# Problem with .focus() in web for iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile-safari

I´m having a problem with the jQuery .focus() function on a web page for iPhone. I have four inputs, when one input reach the maximun of 4 characters the focus have to move to the next input.
This is the code.

```
<input type="password" name="cc_number_1" id="cc_number_1" onkeyup="checkCC1()" maxlength="4">
<input type="password" name="cc_number_2" id="cc_number_2" maxlength="4">


function checkCC1()
{
   if($('#cc_number_1').val().length == 4)
   {
      $('#cc_number_2').focus();
   }
}
```

The problem is that `$('#cc_number_2').focus()` is not working, the focus doesn´t move to the next input.

What i´m doing wrong??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** Original answer removed as it did not solve the problem **

There is supposedly a documented bug on mobile Safari (in fact the webkit engine, so it affects other mobile browsers) that makes the keyboard disappear when the focus changes.  This seems to be what I am seeing when I test.  I am currently looking to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: i tried your code and doesn´t work. Maybe i could try the jquery mobile library.

Answer (score 1):

That problem was probably caused because mobile safari doesn't support the "onKeyUp" event, have you tried "onKeyPress" ? The focus() part could be ok if the event is the cause... IDK